# How to create Twitter android app like progress bar used in polls functionality

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to create exact progress bar like shown in image below with poll option text in left side and percentage text in right side. Also poll option text(left one) should be truncated if large enough.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have a layout with a match parent width and weight sum of 100. In this layout you add a view with blue or grey color and set the weight equals to the poll percentage. Over this layout you put 2 textviews, one in the left and one in the right and put the texts in it.

Comment: This is a rough idea about how this layout should look. https://pastebin.com/bpDbv5Q3

You can make it better by making some reusable items and custom views, but if you just want to have it, here is the xml layout.